# Convertir en un string un elemento de un array en php

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una lista de personas que traigo desde mi `bd`, quiero recorrer esa lista y cambiar de cada persona de mi lista uno de los atributos de la misma q es de tipo `int` como puede ser el documento de la persona y pasar ese parametro de un `int` a un `string`.

Personas.php

```
<?php
class atencion {
public static function get($peticion){
        if ($peticion[0] == 'getAll') {
        return self::getAll();
        }

public static function getAll(){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM persona";

        $sentencia = ConexionBD::obtenerInstancia()->obtenerBD()->prepare($sql);

        try{    
            if ($sentencia->execute()) {
                $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
                return $resultado;  
            }
             else {
                return null;
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            throw new ExcepcionApi(self::ESTADO_FALLA_DESCONOCIDA, "Falla desconocida". $e->getMessage(), 400);
        }
}

public static function post($peticion){

        if ($peticion[0] == 'agregar') {

            return self::agregar();

        }  else {

            throw new ExcepcionApi(self::ESTADO_URL_INCORRECTA, "Url mal formada", 400);

        }

} 

public static function agregar(){

            $body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $input = json_decode($body);
    $array = (array)$input;

        $idPersona = $array['idPersona'];

        $documento = $array['documento'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO persona (idPersona, documento) VALUES(:idPersona, :documento)";

     try{

        $pdo = ConexionBD::obtenerInstancia()->obtenerBD(); 

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':idPersona', $idPersona);

        $stmt->bindParam(':documento', $documento);

        $stmt->execute(); 

        $pdo = null;

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Persona Agregada"}';

     } catch(PDOException $e){

        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';

     }

}
}
```

Comment: Especifica mejor tu duda. ¿Qué te falla?

Comment: @Trewqa el problema esta en que ese `getAll` yo lo llamo desde una `App` y necesito q ese valor `Documento` retorne en `string` desde la consulta `php`

Comment: Si quieres convertir una variable int a string usa `string strval ( mixed $var )`. [Enlace de Referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strval.php)

Comment: No se entiende bien. ¿Tú quieres convertir este valor a String: `$documento = $array['documento'];`? Ten en cuenta que si es para insertarlo en la base de datos no es necesario hacer tal conversión.

Comment: @A.Cedano exactamente quiero tomar el elemento convertirlo en `string` y volver a insertarlo en el `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres tomar el valor de la clave `documento` convertirlo en `string` e insertarlo como tal en el array, puedes hacer esto:

### Si es un array con una sola fila

```
$array=array("idPersona"=>1, "documento"=>7);
$array["strDocumento"]=(string)$array["documento"];
```

Aquí lo que se hace es crear una nueva clave llamada `strDocumento` y guardar en ella el valor de `documento` convertido a `string`.

**Prueba:**
var_dump($array);

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  ["idPersona"]=>
  int(1)
  ["documento"]=>
  int(7)
  ["idDocumento"]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

---

### Si es un array con varias filas

Sería un procedimiento parecido al anterior, pero dentro de un bucle `foreach` que nos permitirá leer las diferentes filas del array:

```
$array=array(
                array("idPersona"=>1, "documento"=>7),
                array("idPersona"=>2, "documento"=>-9),
            );

foreach ($array as $k=>$row){
    $array[$k]["strDocumento"] = (string)$row["documento"];
}
```

**Prueba:**

```
var_dump($array);
```

Se mostrará la nueva clave en el array, con un tipo de dato `string`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idPersona"]=>
    int(1)
    ["documento"]=>
    int(7)
    ["strDocumento"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idPersona"]=>
    int(2)
    ["documento"]=>
    int(-9)
    ["strDocumento"]=>
    string(2) "-9"
  }
}
```